# Wrap string at certain delimiters

Tags: java, regex, formatting

The method receives an unformatted string and it needs to put line breaks after ';' or before 'i)' and 'i.', where i - integer. 
If received a string like '; 1)', then it should add only one line breaker after ';' and before '1)'.

```
// This is ugly - needs to be refined and refactored
private static String format(String unformattedStr) {
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(\\;\\s*)");
    Matcher matcher1 = p1.matcher(unformattedStr);

    String formattedStr1;
    if (matcher1.find()) {
        formattedV1 = matcher1.replaceAll("$1\\\\n");
    } else {
        formattedV1 = unformattedStr;
    }

    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\)|\\d+\\.)");
    Matcher matcher2 = p2.matcher(formattedV1);
    String formattedV2;

    if (matcher2.find()) {
        formattedV2 = matcher2.replaceAll("\\\\n$1");
    }
    else {
        formattedV2 = formattedV1;
    }

    String formattedV3 = formattedV2.replaceAll("\\\\n\\s*(\\\\n)+", "\\\\n");
    return formattedV3;
}
```

Comment: I would change your second regex to "(\d+[).])" With suitable escapes. :)

Comment: Also give proper names to the `Patterns`, `Matchers` and formatted `String`s. For example `semiColonPattern`, `numberingPattern` etc.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have three distinct cases, two of which can be covered with one regex as @EmilyL pointed out already.

So unless I am missing something can't you just do the following?

```
private static String format(String unformattedStr) {    
    return unformattedStr.replaceAll("(;?\\s)(\\d+[).])", "$1\\\\n$2");
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. 
It's missing though the last replace. So if you append another .replaceAll("\\\\n\\s*(\\\\n)+", "\\\\n") I'll accept it.

Comment: Your original explanation mentions three cases and this function returns the same output as your original one as far as I can tell. Could you elaborate which case is missing?

Comment: It's saying "it should add only one line breaker after ';' and before '1)'."
So, for example if the unformattedStr = "foo; 1) bar", then the method will return "foo; \n \n1) bar", and it should return "foo; \n1) bar", which is achieved running the last replace in the original code

Comment: @user3082046 Oh, I misread the OP then. Will the input always have the same structure though? I.e. will it always be `foo; 1)` or `foo; 1.` or can the different tokens appear independent of each other?

Comment: There can be all sorts of combinations:
 `foo; 1) bar` ,  `foo; 1. bar` , `foo; bar` , `foo 1) bar` or `foo 1. bar`.
And for each case `foo` and `bar` should be separated with only one `\n`

Comment: @user3082046 I think we might be able to cover all of the cases with one regex. I'll update the answer.

Comment: it's not working for `foo; bar` case